# String concatination in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Msg1(){
var a="noida";
id=1;
  document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = '<p onclick="nice(id)">'+a+'</p>';
}
function Msg2(){
  document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'Try message 1 again...';
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="Msg1()" value="Show Message 1" />
<input type="button"  onclick="Msg2()" value="Show Message 2" />
<p id="myText"></p>
```

when i click on Show Message 1 it send id as a charecter not 1 i want to it send me 1
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
'<p onclick="nice(\"' + id + '\")">'+a+'</p>';
```

Or:

```
'<p onclick="nice(' + escape(JSON.stringify(id)) + ')">'+a+'</p>';
```

But this gets very unreadable very quickly.

Using this method you can't send things that aren't easily serializable. A more robust, and involved, solution would use the DOM API and EventListener API.

Example:

```
var id = { foo: "bar" };
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.addEventListener("click", function () {
    nice(id);
});
p.innerText = "ipsum lorem";
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: please do some favor if i want send id in double quote. then its not works

Answer (score 0):

You already have concatenation right near where you need it:

```
'<p onclick="nice('+id+')">'+a+'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

make your innerHTML as

```
'<p onclick="nice(\"' + id + '\")">'+a+'</p>'
```

Replace your **Msg1() Javascript function** as below

```
function Msg1(){
   var a="noida";
   var id = 1;
   document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = '<p onclick="nice(\"' + id + '\")">'+a+'</p>';
}
```